# Searching item in a serialized data field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

Suppose I have serialized a column in my model as below,

```
class FatMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data   
end
```

When I do FatMaster.last.data, I get the following result

```
{"Saturated Fat Sensitivity"=>{"result"=>"Normal", "value"=>"10"}, "Polyunsaturated Fat Sensitivity"=>{"result"=>"High", "value"=>"10"}, "Monounsaturated Fat Sensitivity"=>{"result"=>"Normal", "value"=>"10"}}
```

Suppose I want to get the record whose results for 'Saturated Fat Sensitivity', 'Polyunsaturated Fat Sensitivity' and 'Monounsaturated Fat Sensitivity' are 'Normal', 'Normal', Normal' respectively.

I tried this one :

```
FatMaster.all.select { |m| m.data["Saturated Fat Sensitivity"]["result"] == 'Normal' and m.data["Monounsaturated Fat Sensitivity"] == 'Normal' and m.data["Polyunsaturated Fat Sensitivity"] == 'Normal'}
```

but its not working properly

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ['result'] for some keys.
Your query:

```
FatMaster.all.select { |m| m.data["Saturated Fat Sensitivity"]["result"] == 'Normal' 
    and m.data["Monounsaturated Fat Sensitivity"] == 'Normal' 
    and m.data["Polyunsaturated Fat Sensitivity"] == 'Normal'}
```

So, `m.data["Monounsaturated Fat Sensitivity"] == 'Normal'` will compare hash and 'Normal' . Hence you are not getting any result.

You have to get 'result' from all of them. Use:

```
FatMaster.all.select { |m| m.data["Saturated Fat Sensitivity"]["result"] == 'Normal' and m.data["Monounsaturated Fat Sensitivity"]["result"] == 'Normal' and m.data["Polyunsaturated Fat Sensitivity"]["result"] == 'Normal'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't query serialized fields, that's the downside of that feature. If you don't care about slowing down your rails app ( slowing it down *a lot*, especially if the table contains many rows ) you can do the searching on rails , as you correctly imagined.

Just remember that FatMaster.all loads every row in the table in memory, so it's very resource intensive.

I'm not sure why your code isn't working, probably there are no rows which have all results field set to "Normal"

Comment: I have 2-3 such rows

Comment: @user3779329 You query is missing ['result'] for 2 keys check my answer.

Comment: ohh! thanx I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is:

```
FatMaster.all.select do |fat_master| 
  fat_master.data.values.map {|v| v['result'] }.count('Normal') == 3
end
```

#### steps:

1. Mapping the hash values will give us:

   ["Normal", "High", "Normal"]
2. The count will simply see if we have 3 Normals, in our case no, so will get us:

   false